# Calling derived class methods in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, oop, foreach, var

I'm having trouble with this piece of code:

```
List<Person> persons;    

foreach(var p in persons)
    p.Save();
```

There are several classes derived from `Person` all of which have their own `new Save()` method. Unfortunately, the above code only calls the base class' save method, despite the fact that the list contains instances of different types (base class and derived ones).

All derived classes contain all of the base class' fields, only the `Save` method is different so it also saves the derived class' fields.

How do I make that loop call the appropriate `Save` method based on the variable type it's currently iterating through?

Comment: Can you give an example of a derived class' save method?

Comment: @JustinPihony how is that going to help?

Comment: Can you show us how the save method is defined? It's defined as virtual on the Person class correct?

Comment: If you use `new Save()` you dont get to call the method through the typical method overriding / inheritance manner. Please look up what the new keyword does, which is basically the opposite of what you want it to do in this case.

Comment: Okay then. This might be the problem. How do I modify the base and derived methods to make this work?

Answer (score 6):

Method hiding is generally a recipe for disaster. A correct implementation of this scenario would declare `Save()` as `virtual` in the `Person` class and `override` it in derived classes.

For it to work in your case as described above you would need to cast `p` to the appropriate derived class and call `Save()` on it. Depending on what you do or don't know about the object, you may need to dynamically determine the derived type and invoke its `Save()` method using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using reflection

```
List<Person> persons;    

foreach(var p in persons)
    p.GetType().GetMethod("Save").Invoke(p, null);
```

reflection  bit slow If you can change the declaration of save method as virtual and override it in other classes that will be better option than this as lc's answer.

Comment: I just punched this in and it worked. It's a bit strange there isn't a straightforward way to do this without resorting to reflection.

Comment: There *is* a straight forward to do this without resorting to reflection, but you have defined your base class without virtual methods, which is the opposite of what you would normally do if you expect to be able to invoke overridden methods in those sub classes.

Answer (score 0):

This calls the correct method.

```
using System;

namespace Inheritance
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Person
        {
            virtual public void Save()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Person Save");
            }
        }
        public class Emp : Person
        {
            override public void Save() {
                Console.WriteLine("Emp Save");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Emp();
            p.Save();
        }
    }
}
```