# Call derived class method when using base class in foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have the following code which simply loops through a list of EdiElements and validates each one to make sure that it conforms to a set of rules defined as attributes on the derived class.

The problem I am having is with the `elem.Validate()` line which is calling the base class method instead of the derived class method.  The `_elements` list contains different classes that all derive from `EdiElement` and I need to be able to loop through them all and perform validation rules in each of these classes.

What is the standard way of calling a method on a derived class when using the base class as an iterator variable in a foreach loop as in the example below?

```
public override bool Validate()
{
  foreach ( EdiElement elem in _elements )
  {
    if ( !_checkElementIsValid( this, elem ) )
      base.ValidationErrors.Add( string.Format( "Element {0} does not belong to segment {1}", this.GetType().Name, this.GetType().Name ) );
    else
      elem.Validate(); // <-- I want this to call derived class method
  }

  return base.ValidationErrors.Count == 0;
}
```

Edited to show class definitions.

```
public abstract class EdiElement : Edi
{
  public override bool Validate()
  {
    return true; // breakpoint here gets hit
  }
}

public abstract class EdiDataElement<T> : EdiElement
{
  public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class E3286 : EdiDataElement<String>
{
  public override bool Validate()
  {
    return base.Validate(); // breakpoint here does not get hit!
  }
}
```

I forgot to add the base class.

```
public abstract class Edi
{
    protected static List<string> _validationErrors = new List<string>();

    public List<string> ValidationErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return _validationErrors;
        }
    }

    public abstract bool Validate();
}
```

Comment: How are the classes/methods defined?  That is, how is the derived class inheriting/overriding the base class' method?

Comment: The default behavior of `virtual` functions is to use the derived method. Could you show us the class definition?

Comment: Agree with Ben N. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx which says _"At run-time, when client code calls the method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code you can call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of the method to be executed."_

Comment: You are using `virtual`, right? If you're "hiding" by using `new`, that would cause the kind of behavior you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Similar question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971833/calling-derived-class-methods-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: I have edited my post and added the class definitions.

Comment: Are you debugging a debug or release build?

Comment: I am debugging a debug build.

Comment: What is the point of overriding if you are just calling `base.Validate();` anyway?

Comment: Is this happening with `E3286` or `EdiDataElement` classes?

Comment: @mclaassen the reason for `base.Validate()` is just a placeholder as I've got a breakpoint on the line to see if it's getting hit and it isn't.  It will be replaced with proper validation logic once I have resolved the problem.

Comment: Long shot.. can you try replacing `base.Validate()` with something else? Maybe throw an exception or something.

Comment: @MikeClarke - Just return false from the child method and true from the base.  See what happens then.  Don't worry about the actual breakpoints.

Comment: @mclaassen replacing `base.Validate()` with a throw exception does indeed throw an exception.  I am thinking I need to go back to basics and redesign my classes as it's too complex to follow.

Comment: Post amended as I forgot to add the `Edi` base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is going on is somehow (despite debug build and settings) the compiler is optimizing out the call to `base.Validate()` which is why the breakpoint is not being hit.

The following (as per the original class design) works correctly for me:

```
A x = new D();
x.Test();

public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void Test();
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test() in B");
    }
}

public abstract class C<T> : B
{

}

public class D : C<String>
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        base.Test(); //breakpoint hits here
    }
}
```

Comment: Optimize code option is unticked in build properties and I am using a debug build.

Comment: @MikeClarke It must be getting optimized out somehow if by only changing the code inside it is getting executed.

Comment: I will review my code and amend it so that is more or less matches your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve it after changing the `EdiElement` so that it defines an `abstract override` in the `Validate()` method and then override this in the derived classes.  The code is now executing correctly in the manner that I expected.

```
public override bool Validate()
{
  foreach ( EdiElement elem in _elements )
  {
    if ( !_checkElementIsValid( this, elem ) )
      base.ValidationErrors.Add( string.Format( "Element {0} does not belong to segment {1}", this.GetType().Name, this.GetType().Name ) );
    else
      elem.Validate(); // <-- I want this to call derived class method
  }

  return base.ValidationErrors.Count == 0;
}

public abstract class EdiElement : Edi
{
  public abstract override bool Validate();
}

public abstract class EdiDataElement<T> : EdiElement
{
  public T Value { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///  To specify a component of an address.
/// </summary>
[DataElementMetadata(
    Name = "Address component",
    Description = "To specify a component of an address.",
    Type = Types.Type.an,
    Length = "0..70" )]
public class E3286 : EdiDataElement<String>
{
    public override bool Validate()
    {
        base.ValidationErrors.Add( "Validation error!" );
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'd like to thank the community for pointing me in the right direction as I was sure I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm curious, does it hit a break point now if you just have `base.Validate()` inside E3286 `Validate()` method?

Comment: Yes it does hit the breakpoint in the derived class now, inside E3286 `Validate()` method.

Comment: Even when it only has base.Validate() inside?

Comment: Guys, could you please explain it to me: What is `abstract override`? Any link?

Comment: I don't think your modifications should be necessary. I think it is due to some optimization and if you leave it how it was it will work.

Comment: @mclaassen if it was due to some optimization then what would cause the compiler to decide to optimize, even though such a setting is turned off?

Comment: @Love - It means it's both `override` (replaces a parent's version) and `abstract` (declares no definition of its own).  Together, they mean that you're going to have to override it *again* in a child class.

Comment: That I am not sure, but I don't think you need to actually change your class design. i.e. the `abstract override` is not necessary.

Comment: I updated my classes to include the generics just in case and it still works for me. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score -2):

That is a...peculiarity of C#.

If one defines a base class and inherits from it, the default behaviour is that, when an instance is upcast to the base class, overridden methods revert to the base class implementation of the overridden method, unless the override is explicitly marked with the keyword `override`.

If you ask me, this violates a basic tenet of O-O programming (a dog doesn't cease being a dog if you call it an animal). Personally, I think C#'s designers were crocked when the decided on this behavior, but I digress.

For instance this program:

```
class Animal         { public virtual  void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("Most animals make some sort of noise.") ; } }
class Dog : Animal   { public virtual  void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("Dog: Woof!") ; } }
class Cat : Animal   { public new      void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("Meow!") ; } }
class Sheep : Animal { public override void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("Baaa!") ; } }

static void Main( string[] args )
{
  Animal[] menagerie = { new Animal() , new Dog() , new Cat() , new Sheep() , } ;

  foreach ( Animal creature in menagerie )
  {
    Console.Write( "{0}:\t" , creature.GetType().Name ) ;
    creature.Speak() ;
  }

  return;
}
```

produces this output:

```
Animal: Most animals make some sort of noise.
Dog:    Most animals make some sort of noise.
Cat:    Most animals make some sort of noise.
Sheep:  Baaa!
```

This feature means that in a C# program, to get the behavior one would ordinarily expect requires extra work on the part of the developer. Unless there is a specific requirement otherwise, it's good practice to *always* use `abstract`/`virtual` and `override`.

Comment: You get compiler warnings about using a `virtual` method to override a `virtual` method.  Not errors, but you are warned it won't do what you expect.

Comment: The class in the question does use the `override` keyword though.

Comment: @mclaassen is right.  Only the `Sheep` example is valid for the question-as-asked, and that behaves correctly.

Comment: Relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/245393/why-was-c-made-with-new-and-virtualoverride-keywords-unlike-java/245399#245399

Comment: This answer presents very subjective opinions in a way as if they were unquestionably objective truths. For example, I personally "would ordinarily expect" that *overriding* happens *only* when specified (in this case, by using the `override` keyword), but this answer claims the exact opposite as if it were the only true way.